# Clean Architecture and lazy loading of entities in а GraphQL API

Tags: node.js, graphql, clean-architecture

I am trying to improve the architecture of an existing project following the Clean Architecture principles to the best of my ability and understanding, but one of the things that I am struggling with is where to fit lazy loading of entities in GQL Resolvers.

If we consider as an example of having a Product entity, which has associated Categories with it in a One-to-many type of relationship ( in my application, its MTM, but lets go with this for simplicity ), then the corresponding Product type would look similar to this

```
type Category {
  name: String!
  ...
}

type Product {
  ...
  name: String
  description: String
  categories: [Category!]!
}
```

The client can query any of the Product field, which all live in the `products` table, and if he needs to access the categories that this product has been associated with, he can use the `categories` field.

To avoid over-fetching, the right thing seems to be to initially fetch data only from the `products` table, and conditionally load data from the `categories` table if it was asked for by the client.

So, to resolve the categories, we need to conditionally query the `categories` table.

From what I figured out, I could use the Repository pattern to obtain a `Product` domain object and return that to the GrapQL query resolver.

What I do not understand, however, is where should the logic for querying the additional entities live?

For example, if the `Product` domain object was to have a `loadCategories` method, then from the `Categories` resolver I could just call it

```
const resolvers = {
  Product: {
    async categories(product, args, ctx) {
      return product.loadCategories()
    }
  } 
}
```

However, that would require the Product object to depend on the `Repository` or another DAO, which, from what I understand, I am not supposed to do.

Do I inject a `Repository` or a DAO in the `context` object of graphql, and use that one from the resolver?

This one seems like I would be doing it backwards in one way, but in another way - not so much. Because root query resolvers are a bit like controllers, for which is okay to use repositories. But this nested field resolver, in a way, belongs to the `Product` domain object, which I find a bit confusing.

Also, if I have an authorization policy, which, lets say, allows guest users to read the `name` of the product, but not the `description` ( I should return `null` if they cannot read it ), where should that logic live?

Comment: improvement by implementing GQL or improving existing GQL? what do you know about connections/edges/nodes/standard/usual relation implementations/dataloader?

Comment: Improving an existing graphql project. I know enough about all of these, and they are implemented, but I fail to see how any of these things would help me with the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Repositiories or [possibly external] datasources are passed by context ...

'parent', first resolver arg is a [usually] plain object with resolved data properties (f.e. product.id) [usually] required for current resolver [to filter/SQL where] ...

'parent' (Product in this case) resolver can return an object with fields/props ... but you can return more than required for response ... one of them can be a [lazy] initialized `Product` (entity) instance with `getCategories()` [lazy] getter ... but with own repository access? not using ctx passed repositories/datasources? or injected during 'hydrating' ...

... and what this getter should return? Ids only? ACL - `null` in some cases? (use user from context?) ... should it be a minimalistic array of `{id, name/title}` or full Category entries? Again ... it's a `Category` resolver[-s] role

Wouldn't it be too complicated? Maybe suitable for some business logic/fields/props?

ACL for fields? resolver role, too

Any [type] resolver can use repositories ... it's a graph ... not only for root resolvers only ... it would be tight coupling/dependency.

Comment: I do know that every resolver has access to the `context` object, but the root ( query ) resolver is similar to a Controller in a REST api, yes? And the `categories` is a sub-field of the product type, which makes it a bit different. After watching [this talk](https://youtu.be/gb1R-fWP1Yw?t=1178) I got the idea that the Product ( first arg ) may not be a POJO. It might contain the logic for resolving sub-fields. What I do not understand, however, is how, where and should I fit that method on an Entity object ( DDD or Clean Architecture ). Dan also advices against authorization in resolvers.

Comment: updated to clarify some ideas ... subfield without connection means nothing [usable] (it's just DB relation one side encoding/representation) as you want to access connected object properties ... improving without own opinion? BTW, questions about opinions are off-topic on SO ... maybe it should be more about microservices behind 'graphql access layer'?